# Is there a LINQKit version for EF 5.0 ? Otherwise what other could I use for EF 5.0?

Tags: entity-framework, expression, linq-expressions, linqkit

Ey there, I just see the latest LINQKit version depends of EF 6.0.2, I need to install on EF 5.0, is there an older LINQKit version for EF 5.0 compatibility ? Or something else to replace it (.Expand() functionality) ?

Answer (score 6):

The latest version of [LinqKit on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) (1.1.1) indeed depends on EF 6.0.2. (The NuGet package doesn't seem to be maintained by the original author of LinqKit.)

But both version 1.0 on NuGet and the version available directly from [the official site](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) don't have any dependencies, so you can use that from EF 5 or any other LINQ-based ORM.

To install the version 1.0 of the package, you can use the package manager console like this:

```
Install-Package LinqKit -Version 1.0.0
```